# Connection error when using pycharm and pyramid web framework

Tags: python, pycharm, pyramid

I am using pycharm (v4.5.3) and the pyramid web framework (v1.5.7).

I created a simple project, but I got an error when I tried to access the welcome page (that is in my case 0.0.0.0:6543).

Here are the steps I followed:

1. Installed python 3.4.3 and pycharm 4.5.3 (professional edition)
2. Created a project with pycharm (without creating an env because of the pro edition)
3. Selected scaffold "starter" and no template language because I read that could cause an error
4. Using pycharm GUI I ran "setup.py develop".  The server starts at 0.0.0.0:6543 but the connection does not work. According to a video I watched on Youtube, a welcome page should appear. Indeed it appears only if I type "localhost:6543"; however my server is listening on 0.0.0.0:6543.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Why or how are you so sure your server is running on 0.0.0.0 ? I bet it is 127.0.0.1 , hm?

Comment: because in the console appear "0.0.0.0:6543" and also in the tutorial on pyramid site..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[0.0.0.0](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0) is a "meta address" which tells the server to listen on all available local interfaces. This address is non-routable, so you can't access the server by specifying this address - you need a real IP of one of your machine's network interfaces